# How to switch between multiple fullscreen windows of same application in OS X?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, productivity

When I'm running several instances of the same app (might be Chrome separate windows, or several IntelliJ projects) in fullscreen mode, I can't navigate to concrete app using <kbd>⌘-Tab</kbd>, it will just show one icon of the app but there are several running in the background.

Also there is no application specific shortcut to do so.

[image]

Is there a way to make <kbd>⌘-Tab</kbd> show instances rather than global app icon?

Comment: A new window is rarely a new instance, unless you launched it from terminal using `open -n` If it's the same instance, then there's a single icon in switcher.

Comment: no i just type command + N from full screan chrome and it will open new window which is separate instance in mission control but in command + TAB i see only one... try it

Comment: It's not a separate instance, merely another window.

Comment: Ok then how do i navigate to that another window with a shortcut? :) except mission control

Comment: Its a separate chrome window i cant just pres ctrl + tab to switch to next tab. Only option so far i saw was mission control which sucks...

Comment: Cmd ` is next window

Comment: I know about that shorcut :(
and it works only for non full screan apps

Comment: I tought this should be a common problem, as this affects any full screan app that can have few windows/instances i bet i'm not the only one needing to switch between them :) (maybe others just use mission control?)

Comment: It would be better if you reworded your question; adding what you actually need to achieve & what you have tried so far, rather than it requiring 20 questions to extract that information. There is actually no solution to the issue, except to use a shortcut to the 'normal' space, then ctrl/arrow to the 'extra' ones that are generated by fullscreen apps.

Comment: https://github.com/lwouis/alt-tab-macos

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is **no shortcut** to switch between fullscreen windows of the same application.

You have **two alternatives** that are not ideal but enough:

1. Shortcuts to switch between spaces/desktops or jump to a specific one

[image]

2. Gestures to switch between spaces/desktops

[image]

To make this workflow work well, just put your fullscreen windows **side by side**.

Comment: thats what i do now :)
tough it still involves trackpad but it is much easyer and faster now.
still i dont really understand why mac does this, whats the point to tread several instances as one when purpose of command tab is to switch to what you need...

Comment: In the upper image what keypresses do ^← and ^→ represent?

Comment: @hippietrail `^` represents `Ctrl`, so `Ctrl+leftArrow`, `Ctrl+rightArrow`.

Comment: It is worth noting that the `Ctrl` + `Left Arrow` and `Ctrl` + `Right Arrow` shortcuts to switch between spaces are enabled by default.

Answer (score 8):

Apart from Mission Control, there also is the Dock.

When you click repeatedly it will cycle through the application's full screen spaces.

Comment: Oh thanks, i didnt know that, my dock is autohiding tough :) 
and i more tend to use keyboard than trackpad/mouse thus the question, but thanks for an answer :)

Comment: did not know that. thx!  Is there a way to discern on the Dock whether multiple windows exist?  For non fullscreen there are multiple icons. But Fullscreen does not shown AFAICT.

Comment: Nothing out of the ordinary that I know of.  A probably well known one is the 'Window' menu listing of multiple windows, as shown in the original post's screenshot, is mirrored in some applications (e.g. Safari), when the Dock icon is ctrl.-clicked, or right-clicked, or clicked and held.

Comment: I've got an auto-hiding dock too, but I can see the dock from my second monitor... clicking on it doesn't seem to cycle through anything though.

Answer (score 4):

If you know how to bind an applescript to keyboard shortcut/trackpad gesture, this is the answer for you.

The script is meant to be universal. It uses the most generalized terms to include as many scenarios as possible. I've tested on Finder, Script Editor, and Firefox. No errors.

However, it has caveats:

1. The script only works when there's only one instance of an app. (BTW, it still says "several instances" in the text of OP.) It's possible to work multiple-instance into it, but that's a fight for another day.
2. This script scrolls down the list of windows in `Window` menu. It in essence clicks the item right below the one with a check ("✓") mark. If the item with a "✓" is the last item, the script will instead click the first item under the last separator line. A script that goes backward in the reverse direction can be obtained be modifying this script. However, I do not see how the two can be combined into a single script.
3. The `try` statement that produces an `errorMessage` is the most CPU-efficient way I know to produce the index of the `separator`. If you know a better way, please enlighten me.

The script:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell (first application process whose frontmost is true) to tell menu bar 1 to tell menu "Window"

    set cellingSeperator to last menu item whose value of attribute "AXEnabled" is false
    set checkedItem to first menu item whose value of attribute "AXMenuItemMarkChar" is "✓"

    try
        set intentionalError to cellingSeperator as Unicode text
    on error errorMessage
        set firstItemIndex to (characters ((offset of "«class menI» " in errorMessage) + 13) through ((offset of " of" in errorMessage) - 1) of errorMessage as string as integer) + 1
    end try

    repeat with iterator from firstItemIndex to number of menu items
        if value of attribute "AXFrame" of menu item iterator is equal to value of attribute "AXFrame" of checkedItem then
            set clickItemIndex to iterator + 1
            exit repeat
        end if
    end repeat

    if clickItemIndex is greater than number of menu items then set clickItemIndex to firstItemIndex

    tell menu item clickItemIndex to perform action "AXPress"

end tell
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll try it sometime and maybe add the multiInstance part, but i'm new to mac and dont want to do something i dont know how to undo...

This is offtop question but is there a way to backup my os as it is (like a vm) and then if i destroyed something i could recover it from backup... (i dont have the additional time machine thing) just external ssd bigger than my devices memory...

Or any other options you may know of except backup?

Comment: This works, but not so great for me (using Alfred workflows, running script on `osascript`). How would we modify this to work for a specific application? ("Atom" in my case). Maybe it takes a while for System Events to find the correct application etc? I'm not sure why it is slow.

Comment: Will you provide a link to a good how-to for installing scripts like these? Thank you.